# 301 redirect from URL including unicode chacters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, unicode, web-config, http-status-code-301

Tried all possible methods can't make it work. Your help is my last chance!
Have an old and new wordpress website at the same domain.

Trying to 301 redirect from:

`mywebsite.com/שלום` or its encoded version `mywebsite.com/%F9%EC%E5%ED`

to `mywebsite.com/`.

Tried on both plesk and cPanel  with web.config or .htaccess

For example: (.htaccess)

`redirect 301 /%F9%EC%E5%ED http://www.mywebsite.com` 
or 
`redirect 301 /שלום http://www.mywebsite.com`
or
`redirect 301 /שלום /`

But still nothing - no redirect.

Please could anyone show me how to work this out.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that clients will use UTF-8 encoding for that path. Try:

```
/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D
```

You should try to look at your logs to confirm what form the requests are using.